# Laravel, How to store multiple open and close time per every day

Tags: php, laravel

I have array of days and their open time and close time as below, I need to store these days and the open and close time for a selected store in table, in the same time if the store have already entered in this table then update the current records so no duplicate will be found
I hope you can help me in this
many thanks

```
  "store_id" => "625"
      "day_id" => array:7 [
        1 => "1"
        2 => "2"
        3 => "3"
        4 => "4"
        5 => "5"
        6 => "6"
        7 => "7"
      ]
      "open_time" => array:7 [
        1 => "13:20"
        2 => "01:20"
        3 => "13:20"
        4 => "01:20"
        5 => "15:50"
        6 => "07:20"
        7 => "23:20"
      ]

      "close_time" => array:7 [
        1 => "20:20"
        2 => "08:20"
        3 => "20:20"
        4 => "21:20"
        5 => "18:20"
        6 => "00:20"
        7 => "19:20"
      ]
```

I tried with this but need more

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $store_id=$request->storeinfo_id;

    foreach ($request->input('day_id') as $key => $val) {
        $array = [
            'day_id' => $val,
        ];

        Storeday::where('storeinfo_id',$store_id)->create($array);
    }

    return response()->json(['data' => trans('message.success')]);
}
```

Comment: For this I think you need laravel's default methods like `updateOrCreate`, if the record doesn't exist it will be created but if exist it will be updated, go to documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Comment: Move the `Storeday::where('storeinfo_id',$store_id)->create($array)` line to out of the foreach. And you can use Laravel's `updateOrCreate` method.

Comment: can you answer this question we the needed foreach?